# ASP.net all rows editable GridView with list<type> as datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, gridview

Could someone post a working example of a gridview with all rows editable (like it was an excel) and `list<type>` as datasource?

We want to mantain the data the user inputs in the grid between postbacks (that may be generated by any control not only the submit one) and then get the data from the list or the gridview so we use it to insert or update different tables (this is not the typical case of 1:1 relation / grid:sqltable)

Also we have a dropdownlist (with autopostback) with numbers 1 to 9 that controls how many rows are used in the gridview, so if the users changes from 1 to 5 rows 4 new rows will be added to the gridview and if he changes from 8 to 5 rows the last 3 rows will be deleted...(mantaing the data currently inputed by the user)

Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:
ASPX:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNItems" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlNItems_SelectedIndexChanged">
     <asp:ListItem Selected="True">1</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Código">
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCodMuestra" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cod") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tipo">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTipo" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Tipo") %>'>
                      <asp:ListItem Value="a">A</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem Value="b">B</asp:ListItem>
                      <asp:ListItem Value="c">C</asp:ListItem>
                  </asp:DropDownList>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

CS:

```
public class Itemx
{
    public string cod { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
public static List<Itemx> LItems
{
    get
    {
        return (List<Itemx>)Session["LItems"];
    }
    set
    {
        Session["LItems"]= value;
    }
}
void InitializeItems()
{
    LItems = new List<Itemx>();
    ConfigItems();
}
void ConfigItems()
{
    int numitems = Convert.ToInt32(ddlNItems.SelectedValue);


    if (LItems.Count > numitems )
    {
        for (int i = GridView1.Rows.Count; i > numitems; i--)
        {
            LItems.RemoveAt(i - 1);
        }
    }
    else if (LItems.Count < numitems )
    {
        for (int i = GridView1.Rows.Count; i < numitems; i++)
        {
            LItems.Add(new Itemx { Tipo = "a" });
        }
    }
    transferGridtoList();

    GridView1.DataSource = LItems;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
}
private void transferGridtoList()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < LItems.Count && i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        LItems[i].cod = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Controls[1]).Text;
        LItems[i].Tipo = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Controls[1]).SelectedValue;
    }
}

protected void ddlNItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConfigItems();
}
```